# Steam stopped working ubuntu mate 20.04

Tags: steam, mate

Steam was working fine until a week or so ago, and now when I try to start it up I get this:

You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libXrandr.so.2
libXrender.so.1
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libgio-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpipewire-0.3.so.0
libpulse.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libva.so.2
libbz2.so.1.0
libva-drm.so.2
libva.so.2
libva-x11.so.2
libvdpau.so.1

It then tries to start up, and says that steamui couldn't be started. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and it still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you installed Steam? Please add output of `apt-cache policy "steam*"`, `snap list | grep -i steam`, `flatpak list | grep -i steam` and `which steam` with `steam --version` to the question by editing it. It is a bit strange that your Steam version requires `libpipewire-0.3.so.0` library which is not available for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try reinstalling the packages which provide needed libraries by using command below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libbz2-1.0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpipewire-0.3.so.0 libpulse0:i386 libva2:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386
```